# SSL cert for GoDaddy and ElasticBeanStalk

Tags: ssl

A website that i am developing requires a SSL key. The domain will be hosted by Godaddy but the actual content will be hosted on a ElasticBeanStalk reference. Now the domain name for simplicity same is xyz.com but the API on ElasticBeanStalk is xyz.elasticbeanstalk.com. Now i wish to secure my api by a SSL cert. I have purchased the SSL from godaddy, but when i deploy to aws, the browser gives a SSL error that the certificate does not match the domain. So what do i have to do now.

1) Buy two certificates one for my site and the second for the aws instance. 
2) Buy a certificate for *.abc.com and change the AWS api to api.xyz.com or something like that.

What would you guys recommend in this case ?

Answer (score 1):

> The domain will be hosted by Godaddy but the actual content will be hosted on a ElasticBeanStalk reference

I think that you mean that the domain is registered with Godaddy who also provide the DNS, and that your regular web site is also at godaddy. Is that correct?

Either one of your suggestions will work, a wildcard SSL cert (for *.xyz.com) is usually more expensive than two simple ones.

This is a link to the elastic Beanstalk guide on setting up a private SSL cert. Just do what written :) 
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/configuring-https.html